# Computing the convex hull boundaries

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convex-hull

I am trying to compute convex hull boundaries and points in a image. This is what I have done so far to compute the convex hull area.

In the final subplot I want to compute the convex hull points in the image and connect these points. Can anyone help me here?

The input image is present in this [link](http://postimg.org/image/bj4cbuvxp/)

Thanks..

```
subplot(2,2,1);
I = imread('shape.jpg');
imshow(I);
title('Original');

subplot(2,2,2);
BW = im2bw(I, 0.5);
BW = imcomplement(BW);
imshow(BW);
title('Binary');

subplot(2,2,3);
CH_objects = bwconvhull(BW,'objects');
imshow(CH_objects);
title('Objects Convex Hull');
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what your goal is, you can do something like that:

```
close all; 

figure(1);
subplot(2,2,1);
I = imread('shape.jpg');
imshow(I);
title('Original');

subplot(2,2,2);
BW = im2bw(I, 0.5);
BW = imcomplement(BW);
imshow(BW);
title('Binary');

subplot(2,2,3);
CH_objects = bwconvhull(BW,'objects');
imshow(CH_objects);
title('Objects Convex Hull');

figure(2);
[r,c]=find(CH_objects);
CH=convhull(r,c);
plot(r(CH),c(CH),'*-');

figure(3);
[r2,c2]=find(BW);
CH2=convhull(r2,c2);
plot(r2(CH2),c2(CH2),'*-');
```

Let's see what this code does in more detail.
For the sake of clarity I plotted the final plots in `figure(2)` and `figure(3)`, so the `subplot()` does not change.
However on `CH_objects`, we use `find()` to estrapolate the coordinates (rows `r1` and columns `c1`) of all the white points. On these points we perform the convex hull and the indices of the convex hull points are returned in `CH1`.  Now in `figure(2)` we plot the coordinates of such points where each point is marked with a star `*`, along with the normal lines that connect such points.
Also, you can do the very same thing but starting from the BW image and not from `CH_objects`. So you open a third figure and repeat the very same procedure, but starting from `BW` instead.

In this case `figure(1)` will return (as in your case)

[image]

whereas `figure(2)` will return

[image]

and finally `figure(3)` will return

[image]

Obviously feel free to rearrange such plot(s) in your subplot. You can choose either the first or second solution, depending on whether you want to use the 3rd (`CH_objects`) or the 2nd (`BW`) image as starting point.